Not able to load a Vision Transformer model post training
So I am using the example of the vision transformer model for image classification provided on the Keras website. The only difference is I have added a line to save the model once it is done training as a ".keras" file.
Later I try to load the saved model and check it's configuration using "get_configuration()".
Lmodel=load_model("VITexp.keras")
Lmodel.get_config()

But the code fails to load the model and gives me the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py:208, in Operation.from_config(cls, config)
    207 try:
--> 208     return cls(**config)
    209 except Exception as e:

TypeError: Patches.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/serialization_lib.py:718, in deserialize_keras_object(config, custom_objects, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    717 try:
--> 718     instance = cls.from_config(inner_config)
    719 except TypeError as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py:210, in Operation.from_config(cls, config)
    209 except Exception as e:
--> 210     raise TypeError(
    211         f"Error when deserializing class '{cls.__name__}' using "
    212         f"config={config}.\n\nException encountered: {e}"
    213     )

TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'Patches' using config={'name': 'patches_1', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'patch_size': 6}.

Exception encountered: Patches.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/serialization_lib.py:718, in deserialize_keras_object(config, custom_objects, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    717 try:
--> 718     instance = cls.from_config(inner_config)
    719 except TypeError as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/model.py:517, in Model.from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
    515     from keras.src.models.functional import functional_from_config
--> 517     return functional_from_config(
    518         cls, config, custom_objects=custom_objects
    519     )
    521 # Either the model has a custom __init__, or the config
    522 # does not contain all the information necessary to
    523 # revive a Functional model. This happens when the user creates
   (...)
    526 # In this case, we fall back to provide all config into the
    527 # constructor of the class.

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py:517, in functional_from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
    516 for layer_data in config["layers"]:
--> 517     process_layer(layer_data)
    519 # Then we process nodes in order of layer depth.
    520 # Nodes that cannot yet be processed (if the inbound node
    521 # does not yet exist) are re-enqueued, and the process
    522 # is repeated until all nodes are processed.

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py:501, in functional_from_config.<locals>.process_layer(layer_data)
    500 else:
--> 501     layer = serialization_lib.deserialize_keras_object(
    502         layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects
    503     )
    504 created_layers[layer_name] = layer

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/serialization_lib.py:720, in deserialize_keras_object(config, custom_objects, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    719 except TypeError as e:
--> 720     raise TypeError(
    721         f"{cls} could not be deserialized properly. Please"
    722         " ensure that components that are Python object"
    723         " instances (layers, models, etc.) returned by"
    724         " `get_config()` are explicitly deserialized in the"
    725         " model's `from_config()` method."
    726         f"\n\nconfig={config}.\n\nException encountered: {e}"
    727     )
    728 build_config = config.get("build_config", None)

TypeError: <class '__main__.Patches'> could not be deserialized properly. Please ensure that components that are Python object instances (layers, models, etc.) returned by `get_config()` are explicitly deserialized in the model's `from_config()` method.

config={'module': None, 'class_name': 'Patches', 'config': {'name': 'patches_1', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'patch_size': 6}, 'registered_name': 'Custom>Patches', 'build_config': {'input_shape': [None, 72, 72, 3]}, 'name': 'patches_1', 'inbound_nodes': [{'args': [{'class_name': '__keras_tensor__', 'config': {'shape': [None, 72, 72, 3], 'dtype': 'float32', 'keras_history': ['data_augmentation', 0, 0]}}], 'kwargs': {}}]}.

Exception encountered: Error when deserializing class 'Patches' using config={'name': 'patches_1', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'patch_size': 6}.

Exception encountered: Patches.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 Lmodel=load_model("VITexp.keras")
      2 Lmodel.get_config()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_api.py:176, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    173         is_keras_zip = True
    175 if is_keras_zip:
--> 176     return saving_lib.load_model(
    177         filepath,
    178         custom_objects=custom_objects,
    179         compile=compile,
    180         safe_mode=safe_mode,
    181     )
    182 if str(filepath).endswith((".h5", ".hdf5")):
    183     return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(
    184         filepath, custom_objects=custom_objects, compile=compile
    185     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py:152, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    147     raise ValueError(
    148         "Invalid filename: expected a `.keras` extension. "
    149         f"Received: filepath={filepath}"
    150     )
    151 with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
--> 152     return _load_model_from_fileobj(
    153         f, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode
    154     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py:170, in _load_model_from_fileobj(fileobj, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    168 # Construct the model from the configuration file in the archive.
    169 with ObjectSharingScope():
--> 170     model = deserialize_keras_object(
    171         config_dict, custom_objects, safe_mode=safe_mode
    172     )
    174 all_filenames = zf.namelist()
    175 if _VARS_FNAME + ".h5" in all_filenames:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/serialization_lib.py:720, in deserialize_keras_object(config, custom_objects, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    718     instance = cls.from_config(inner_config)
    719 except TypeError as e:
--> 720     raise TypeError(
    721         f"{cls} could not be deserialized properly. Please"
    722         " ensure that components that are Python object"
    723         " instances (layers, models, etc.) returned by"
    724         " `get_config()` are explicitly deserialized in the"
    725         " model's `from_config()` method."
    726         f"\n\nconfig={config}.\n\nException encountered: {e}"
    727     )
    728 build_config = config.get("build_config", None)
    729 if build_config and not instance.built:

TypeError: <class 'keras.src.models.functional.Functional'> could not be deserialized properly. Please ensure that components that are Python object instances (layers, models, etc.) returned by `get_config()` are explicitly deserialized in the model's `from_config()` method.

Exception encountered: <class '__main__.Patches'> could not be deserialized properly. Please ensure that components that are Python object instances (layers, models, etc.) returned by `get_config()` are explicitly deserialized in the model's `from_config()` method.

config={'module': None, 'class_name': 'Patches', 'config': {'name': 'patches_1', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'patch_size': 6}, 'registered_name': 'Custom>Patches', 'build_config': {'input_shape': [None, 72, 72, 3]}, 'name': 'patches_1', 'inbound_nodes': [{'args': [{'class_name': '__keras_tensor__', 'config': {'shape': [None, 72, 72, 3], 'dtype': 'float32', 'keras_history': ['data_augmentation', 0, 0]}}], 'kwargs': {}}]}.

Exception encountered: Error when deserializing class 'Patches' using config={'name': 'patches_1', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'patch_size': 6}.

Exception encountered: Patches.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

The code is copy pasted from the website except for the save and load model commands.
Please help me solve this. Is there a specific way to save these models to be accessed later in completely different notebooks?
(I am using Kaggle for this code)

Take a look at this keras tutorial under the section Custom objects. Specifically the part with "registering custom objects". I think you have to add a @keras.saving.register_keras_serializable() decorator to the class.

Thank you for the comment. I am sorry I forgot to mention, I was prompted to use that for the Patches class. So I did that already.

Try passing **kwargs as a parameter to both the custom layer init() and the super call inside, like mentioned at this github post. Your layer likely gets the default parameters for a layer class its inherited, but can't deal with the parameters like name, as it is not an expected parameter.

Thank you! It worked out. Had to do the same with the 'PatchEncoder' class, but now it is giving me  new error:
'TypeError: PatchEncoder.init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'projection_dim''

You can try to add the projection_dim parameter to the config dict in the get_config method. I'm still not sure which parameters has to get added there and which not.

Thanks I will try that. Is there a way to know which parameters go where? I just want to build a model that I can import in other notebooks without this much hassle. As of now, it seems if I want to load this model elsewhere, there is a bunch of stuff I have to copy over from this like the classes and stuff. I was working with CNNs before this and it was so much easier.

To sum up my comments under the question and give a comprehensive answer, below the code. I used the code from the link in the question, added lines by me are marked by # comments. Only the layer classes have to be modified.
@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()  # <- this line
class Patches(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, patch_size, **kwargs):  # <- add **kwargs
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # <- add **kwargs
        self.patch_size = patch_size

    def call(self, images):
        input_shape = ops.shape(images)
        batch_size = input_shape[0]
        height = input_shape[1]
        width = input_shape[2]
        channels = input_shape[3]
        num_patches_h = height // self.patch_size
        num_patches_w = width // self.patch_size
        patches = keras.ops.image.extract_patches(images, size=self.patch_size)
        patches = ops.reshape(
            patches,
            (
                batch_size,
                num_patches_h * num_patches_w,
                self.patch_size * self.patch_size * channels,
            ),
        )
        return patches

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({"patch_size": self.patch_size})
        return config

# ------------------------------------------------------------------


@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()  # this line
class PatchEncoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_patches, projection_dim, **kwargs):  # <- add **kwargs
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # <- add **kwargs
        self.num_patches = num_patches
        self.projection_dim = projection_dim  # save projection_dim
        print(f'num_patches: {num_patches}, proj. dim: {projection_dim}')
        self.projection = layers.Dense(units=projection_dim)
        self.position_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=num_patches, output_dim=projection_dim
        )

    def build(self, input_shape):  # add build method (this threw only a warning)
        super().build(input_shape)

    def call(self, patch):
        positions = ops.expand_dims(
            ops.arange(start=0, stop=self.num_patches, step=1), axis=0
        )
        projected_patches = self.projection(patch)
        encoded = projected_patches + self.position_embedding(positions)
        return encoded

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({"num_patches": self.num_patches})
        config.update({"projection_dim": self.projection_dim})  # this line
        return config


Short explanation of the added code lines:
@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()

This decorator registers the custom layer for Keras to know about, registering it in a master list.
**kwargs

Catch unknown (to the user) keyword arguments the __init__() method gets and give them to the super() call. In this case, __init__() got the parameter name, because every Layer class gets one. But name was initially not an expected parameter.
self.projection_dim = projection_dim
# ...
config.update({"projection_dim": self.projection_dim})

This two lines save projection_dim to the config of the PatchEncoder layer. This is done to use the set parameter when loading the layer again.

Thank you so much! This works perfectly. The only thing is I have to copy over the layer classes to access this model in any separate notebook. Is there a way to have it not depend on that?
Thanks again!
